# SQL LIKE "String contains word"

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-like

I'm trying to setup a query that will return all rows in the database with the same subject.

Let's say our subject is: "We love beer."
I want to return every row that contains the word "beer"
So it will show titles like "Beer is cool" or "Beer is very nice"
I want to return every row that contains the word beer. But the problem is, the subject is not always the same..

So I tried this in MySQLi:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cms_news WHERE subject LIKE '%".$subject."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Whoops-> Query failed!');
```

But it only returns itself, the row with the exact same title.
Now I read something about the SQL CONTAIN function, but I can't quite understand how it works.

Comment: You need to use `LIKE '%beer%'` not `LIKE '%We love beer%'`

Comment: Or you should implement full-text indexing.

Comment: I don't think there's a `CONTAIN` function in MySQL.

Comment: How do you know that "beer" is the focal point of the query? Why not "love"?

Comment: The subject is a string from the database. That's the problem..

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: If you echo the $subject and then die() immediately before the you build the $query, what does it say?

Comment: @pendo It says "We love beer.", per the second sentence of the question.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: I want it to return subjects of the same kind, so if my subject is "Cool kids" and there is  more articles with let's say the subject "Cool dogs" i want it to return every row with the word "Cool" in it.

Comment: How do you know that "kids" would be the irrelevant word in that context? Maybe you should return "Bad kids" instead of "Cool dogs". I am not trying to harass you, I am trying to figure out your logic.

Comment: Is there any other metadata (like a category or a tag) that could have the word beer in it?  Because, I'm assuming you want to use this for other subjects than just beer.  A hack way around it would be to explode() and then always choose the last word....this would require you stick to a naming convention for subjects.  And yes per @JayBlanchard, please protect your query from SQL injection.

Comment: I will protect my query, thanks for the advice. I'll try to explode()

Comment: Thank you so much @pendo i exploded the string and took the first word, and it works! Thank you!

Comment: Wild card the `subject` and use it against `$subject`.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would suggest you using PDO

```
$var1="some value here"
$query = "SELECT * FROM cms_news  WHERE subject LIKE ? ";
$params = array("%$var1%");
$stmt = $handle->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question; neither securely nor insecurely.

Comment: I suggested pdo and prepared statement, just to put in good habit. As far I know my code will work

Comment: The question is about loose matching not PDO vs. mysqli.